# I am try to get result as an integer while I want take input from user, but my code is not executing

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code which is not getting executed.

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
print(format(n/m.%d))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please take some time to read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve your questions in future. "My code is not getting executed" isn't very helpful compared to including the actual Syntax Error output that you have presumably received when trying to run this, It will also help you learn about how to format code in your question so that it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for your format is incorrect. If you want, print it simply using the float method, since that seems to be doing the same thing as what you are trying to achieve. This can be done by using the following print statement:

```
print(int(m/n))
```

This will print the answer as a int.
The rest of your code works fine.